# Mocking the $injector Service

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, dependency-injection, mocking, jasmine

I have a situation where I want to add services *inside* a module, as I may not know what they are beforehand. From looking at the docs, it seems that the only way to do this (without global scope) is with Angular's `$injector` service. However, it seems that this service is not mockable, which makes sense as it is the way Angular itself gets the dependencies, which are still important even in testing.

Essentially, I am emulating `NodeJS`'s `passport` module. I want to have something like a keychain, where you add or remove an account during runtime. So far, I have this:

```
angular.module('myModule').factory('accounts', function($injector) {
  return {
    add: function(name) {
      if(!$injector.has(name) {
        $log.warn('No Angular module with the name ' + name + ' exists. Aborting...');
        return false;
      }
      else {
        this.accounts[name] = $injector.get(name);
        return true;
      }
    },
    accounts: []
  };
});
```

However, whenever I try to mock the `$injector` function in `Jasmine`, like this:

```
describe('accounts', {
  var $injector;
  var accounts;

  beforeEach(function() {
    $injector = {
      has: jasmine.createSpy(),
      get: jasmine.createSpy()
    };

    module(function($provide) {
      $provide.value('$injector', $injector);
    });

    module('ngMock');
    module('myModule');

    inject(function(_accounts_) {
      accounts = _accounts_;
    });
  });

  describe('get an account', function() {
    describe('that exists', function() {
      beforeEach(function() {
        $injector.has.and.returnValue(true);
      });

      it('should return true', function() {
        expect(accounts.add('testAccount')).toEqual(true);
      });
    });

    describe('that doesn't exist', function() {
      beforeEach(function() {
        $injector.has.and.returnValue(false);
      });

      it('should return true', function() {
        expect(accounts.add('testAccount')).toEqual(false);
      });
    });
  });
});
```

the 2nd test fails because the `accounts` service is calling the actual `$injector` service, and not the mock. I can confirm this by calling `$injector.get` or `$injector.has` during the test or in the service itself.

What should I do? There seems to be no other way to add new dependencies, but this is exactly what I want to do. Am I wrong? Is there in fact another way to do this, without using `$injector`?

Assuming I am right, and there is no other way to do what I want to do, how should I go about testing this function? I could just trust that the `$injector` service does its job, but I still want to mock it for the tests. I could manually add the dependencies during the `inject` function, but that doesn't replicate the actual behavior. I could just not test the function, but then I wouldn't be testing the function.